# Is is possible on iPad OS to detect if the keyboard is in floating mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, ipad, react-native-ios

We're running into a specific bug on `iOS/iPadOS` which seems to be triggered when the iPad is showing the floating (iphone-like) keyboard on screen (instead of the anchored one)

Our issue is specific to React Native and the `KeyboardAvoidingView` component. When the component renders and the keyboard is floating, the `KeyboardAvoidingView` completely mis-calculated the height required for the keyboard and hides about 95% of the screen height instead.

The `KeyboardAvoidingView` itself doesn't seem to have a way to detect whether or not the floating keyboard is on.

Is there a particular API that can be tapped into to detect this keyboard mode so we can turn off the `KeyboardAvoidingView` for it?

The Keyboard events (`keyboardWillShow`, `keyboardDidShow`, etc) don't seem to return any specific clues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such mode enum/indicator (at least for now), but having keyboard frame information

> ```
> public class let keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey: String // NSValue of CGRect
> public class let keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey: String // NSValue of CGRect
> ```

in corresponding keyboard notifications

> ```
> public class let keyboardWillShowNotification: NSNotification.Name
>
> public class let keyboardDidShowNotification: NSNotification.Name
>
> public class let keyboardWillHideNotification: NSNotification.Name
>
> public class let keyboardDidHideNotification: NSNotification.Name
>
> public class let keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification: NSNotification.Name
>
> public class let keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification: NSNotification.Name
> ```

relative to screen bounds

```
UIScreen.main.bounds
```

it is possible to detect if the frame of keyboard is at the edge of screen bottom or floating.

Schematically it would be like

```
keyboardAttached = NSMaxX(screenBounds) == NSMaxX(keyboardFrame) &&
    NSMaxY(screenBounds) == NSMaxY(keyboardFrame) && 
    NSWidth(screenBounds) == NSWidth(keyboardFrame)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer on this. We did think about checking the keyboard dimension but that didn't seem like a reliable solution. We'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Ben As of now i think you guys should use the above approach and keep going until another better solution comes up.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather check against the width of the keyboard.

When the keyboard's frame width is equal to the screen's bounds width THEN it means that the keyboard isn't in floating mode.

Comment: Not true, even with iOS 13 on iPad you get the 'undocked' option when keyboard is full width but not docked

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyboard frame and compare it with the device screen bounds to identify the keyboard type.

```
// Observer for keyboard frame change
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardChange), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

 @objc func keyboardChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        
     guard let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
         return
     }
     let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
     let keyboardFloating = !(screenBounds.maxX == keyboardFrame.maxX &&
                              screenBounds.maxY == keyboardFrame.maxY &&
                              screenBounds.width == keyboardFrame.width)
        
     print("is keyboard floating : ", keyboardFloating)
     if keyboardFloating {
         // floating keyboard
     } else {
         // attached keyboard
     }
}
```

Can use this with any keyboard notifications

- UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
- UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification
- UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification
- UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification
- UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
- UIResponder.keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification